# Apache2 won't start after removing nginx

Tags: nginx, apache2

I stop nginx, removed it, rebooted, installed Apache2 and reinstalled php5-fpm.

Now when I try to start Apache I get this error:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

When I run a netstat I see this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1613/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1850/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1613/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1850/java
```

After I removed Nginx I did a purge as well.

Can someone tell me how to remove these remaining remnants so I can start
Apache2? Also - I can't figure out what is serving my web page…lol..but the site is up.

Thank you for any help!
Tri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php5-fpm` is only relevant if you're running nginx. If you want to run apache instead, stop and remove `php5-fpm`. Also, make sure php is compiled `--with-apache` and not `--with-fpm`. When running apache with php, also make sure the `libphp5.so` module is loaded in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Thank you! I am running php5 - not with fpm - I had already removed that. Any thoughts on the port 80 issue?

Comment: Try running a ps -ef and see if you can spot a running web server, either nginx or apache. Kill any relevant processes.

Comment: Thanks again Asaph! I must've been delusional - but all the nginx folders where still there even though I could've sworn I deleted them. So, did the remove and a reboot (again;) and everything is working.